# Web Api Odata open types $orderby $filter

Tags: odata, webapi

I am using open types in one of my models like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> FieldValues { get; set; }
```

Works great for creating a dynamic list of Fields and Values until I want to use odata `$orderby` or `$filter` queries on one of the fields. If I try to I get

> Only ordering by properties is supported for non-primitive collections. Expressions are not supported.

Which makes sense to me, but I need to come up with some solution that allows me to create a dynamic list of Key/Values and then be able to `orderby` and filter on them?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is this [pull request](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/pull/250) can do, you can get master branch after this checked in, maybe next time you can open an issue in github for us to track, thanks.

This pull request is checked in today, get master branch form github can resolve this issue, or you can use V5.5, which will be released by the end of this month